# Angularjs service with Facebook Messenger extensions sdk methods

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-service, facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

I have some problems to build a service in angularjs using **Facebook Messenger SDK**. I'm using angularjs in a Messenger extensions webview for control all frontend's logic, but i need use messenger extensions sdk for [get facebook user id](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/webview/userid).

```
<script>
  (function(d, s, id){
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.com/en_US/messenger.Extensions.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  }(document, 'script', 'Messenger'));

  window.extAsyncInit = function() {
    // the Messenger Extensions JS SDK is done loading 
  };
</script>
```

In [facebook documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/webview/extensions#add-js) said that to load a SDK insert this code after open `body` tag, and when this is loaded, the function called `window.extAsyncInit()` are been called. After this, i can access to all methods in sdk using `MessengerExtensions` like this:

```
MessengerExtensions.getContext('YOUR_APP_ID', 
  function success(result){
    ...
  },
  function error(result){
   ...
  }
);
```

How can i do a service that use a methods inside MessengerExtension using angularjs?

I tried with next code, but when angularjs is loaded, the variable called MessengerExtension is undefined, because SDK is not loaded.

```
.factory('messengerService', function($q) {
  var appId = 'YOUR_APP_ID';
  return {
    getContext: function() {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        // In this point MessengerExtensions is undefined
        MessengerExtensions.getContext(  appId, function success(response) {
           deferred.resolve(response);
        }, function error(error){
           deferred.reject(error);
        });
        return deferred.promise;
    }
  }
})
.controller("mainController", function($scope, messengerService){
  messengerService.getContext().then( function success(){
    console.log(result) 
  })
});
```

this code returns `ReferenceError: MessengerExtensions is not defined at Object.getContext`

¿How can i solve this?

Thanks and sorry for my english level!

Comment: This article might help: https://www.jvandemo.com/how-to-properly-integrate-non-angularjs-libraries-in-your-angularjs-application/

Comment: thanks @amuramoto ! Very interesting article! I'm trying this, but this not solve my problem. In the article mentions that when factory is loaded, if "magical variable" is empty, the program apply other logic, but i no need other logic. I need that when "magical variable" appears, methods can be accessed o the method in the controller can be executed. I go trying other ways, but very very thanks for reply.